# Deploying the EJB in LifeRay bundled JBoss 5.1.0

Tags: liferay, jboss5.x

I have downloaded the Liferay Bundled Jboss version 5.10. GA.. Everything went well with respect to liferay portals.When I started to deploy the EAR in this JBOSS,it throws the following exception

---

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InterceptorInfoRepository.initialise(InterceptorInfoRepository.java:107)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3HandlerFactory$DDFactory.(Ejb3HandlerFactory.java:48)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3HandlerFactory.getInstance(Ejb3HandlerFactory.java:83)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deploy(Ejb3Deployment.java:611)    at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.create(Ejb3Deployment.java:491)     at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:182)..

---

But the same EAR has successfully deployed in normal JBOSS 5.1.0 GA.... So can anyone please tell me what could be problem. Is the JBOSS bundled with liferay is not supporting the EJB or some other issues.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one checks the [JBoss tip page](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen14-installing-liferay-on-jboss-51-0), following was removed. EJB3 deployment is impacted as a result.

1. Remove the following files from

   ```
   $JBOSS_HOME/../server/default/deploy: /messaging
   ejb2-container-jboss-beans.xml ejb2-timer-service.xml
   ejb3-connections-jboss-beans.xml ejb3-container-jboss-beans.xml
   ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml ejb3-timerservice-jboss-beans.xml
   hsqldb-ds.xml jms-ra.rar mail-ra.rar mail-service.xml
   profile-service-secured.jar uuid-key-generator.sar
   ```
2. Delete the following in $JBOSS_HOME/../server/default/deployers:

   ```
   jboss-ejb3-endpoint-deployer.jar 
   messaging-definitions-jboss-beans.xml"
   ```